# Azure search filter with ping's in the search result

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am building an app where you can search for gamers. I have the filter below:

var filter = $"(Game/any(x: search.in(x, '{string.Join("|", query.Games)}', '|')))";

The property Game is a an Edm.Collection and if one or more of the words in Games are pressent in the query.Games list then there should be a match. This works fine in most scenarios. But not if one of the games contains ' (ping). Ping is not a special character how should this be escaped?

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are reserved characters in the OData filter syntax. Single quotes (') are used to delimit the literal being used in the filter expression. To work around this, you can add an additional single quote to the one in the name of your game and it would be interpreted as a quote that's part of the text.

For ex. if you have game named **ga'me2**, you can use it in the filter as shown below.

```
$filter=Game/any(x: search.in(x, 'game1, ga''me2')
```

For your case, you will probably have to do a String.Replace on individual game names.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried double quoting but it returns zero results. All other categories works except with '. Following query was used: (SubGroups/any(x: search.in(x, 'Tom Clancy''s Rainbow Six')))

Comment: Can you share your index schema and the analyzers being used. Keep in mind that filtering treats the text passed in as a keyword. In your case, **Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six** is a single token and it should exist in the index as is for the filter to match. You can also look at the individual tokens being indexed using the analyze  API and the particular analyzer used for indexing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer

Comment: @IshanSrivastava This shouldn't have anything to do with analyzers, since it's in the context of filters and search.ismatch[scoring] isn't being used.

ThomasSegato: If you use eq instead of search.in() to filter that one item, does it change the results?

Comment: I will follow up @bruse.

Comment: It is not possible to use equal on collection properties:  Invalid expression: The operand for a binary operator 'Equal' is not a single value. Binary operators require both operands to be single values.